# Calling a class and methods from another class, non-statically

Tags: php

I'm trying to instantiate a class from PHP from another class, as well as calling methods of said class, but no matter what I do, I recieve errors.

Why won't the following work:

```
class Example {
    public function sayHi () {
        echo "hi";
    }
}

class Caller {
    private $_controller,
            $_action;

    public function __construct ($cont, $action) {
        $this->_controller = $cont;
        $this->_action = $action;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string)$this->_action;
    }

    public function run () {
        $controller = new $this->_controller;
        if (is_callable(array($controller, $this->_action))) {
            $controller->$this->_action;
        }
    }
}

$caller = new Caller ('Example', 'sayHi');
$caller->run();
```

When changing the method run to the following works?

```
public function run () {
    $controller = new $this->_controller;
    if (is_callable(array($controller, $this->_action))) {
        call_user_func(array($this->_controller, $this->_action));
    }
}
```

The reason why I don't want call_user_func, is because it calls the controller statically.

Removing the magic method __toString gives me:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Caller could not be converted to string
```

Adding it again gives me the following:

```
Undefined property: Example::$sayHi (same line, on method run() from Caller)
Trying to get property of non-object (same line, on method run() from Caller)
```

Comment: So what errors you receive?

Comment: What errors are you getting? And do yo have a specific question here?

Comment: You don't even try to use the Example class... What are you trying to do here? What doesn't work? You need to give us more information!

Comment: Added errors. And afaik, it's pretty easy to see what I'm trying to do? Call a class and methods from another class?

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen see my answer below, one code tweak and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're partially right. If you simply pass a class name and function to `call_user_func` it will call it statically. But if you pass an instance to it, it will call it within that instance. That's what [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)s are.

Comment: Why didn't I know this. This is a tremendous help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This line is your problem:

```
$controller->$this->_action;
```

Couple issues here. For one, you don't have parens at the end to indicate you are calling a method. PHP thinks you are trying to access a property.

Secondly, you want to get the value first for `$this->_action` and then use that value dynamically as the method name. Use curly braces to separate this out.

Change that line to this:

```
$controller->{$this->_action}();
```

And it works: http://3v4l.org/2B0qg

Comment: Thank you, however I went with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21053099/1478808) approach. Didn't know it required curlies there!